# SSIS 2008 create new folder and copy

Tags: ssis

in SSIS 2008, In my incremental process, I would like to create automatically a new folder containing the current date.
Then copy all files from a source directoty to this new folder...

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance
Largo

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Execute Process" to run a robocopy .bat file to copy the files.
Create a local variable and assign it in a C# script to get the current date.

```
Dts.Variables["User::CurrentDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Found a easier way to add the date. follow the link
http://www.sqlnerd.com/ssis_dynamic_dates.htm